# could not load jnetpcap.so file in java on debian wheezy

Tags: java, debian, libpcap, jnetpcap

I'm using **jnetpcap v1.3** in my java project and the so file it uses for native calls has a dependency on **libpcap0.9** but my libpcap version is **0.8** and cannot find this library in apt repositories.

so how can i install libpcap0.9 on debian wheezy to solve this dependency problem?

p.s.: using command '**ld libjnetpcap.so**' I found the broken dependency link.

Answer (score 0):

> the so file it uses for native calls has a dependency on libpcap0.9

Debian doesn't *have* a libpcap0.9:

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libpcap&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libpcap0.9&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all

It appears that there may have been a libpcap0.9 at one point, but [they got rid of it because it had no reason to exist](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=318654).  As that report says, "The libpcap0.9 source package isn't needed anymore, it turns out that version 0.9 of libpcap is API and ABI compatible with libpcap0.8".

They'll probably only change the name to something other than "libpcap0.8" if the API or the ABI changes in an incompatible fashion, and I have no intention of *ever* letting the published libpcap APIs or ABIs change in a fashion that's breaks compatibility with programs built with an earlier version of libpcap (note that the layout of a `pcap_t` structure is *not* part of the published API or ABI...).  So, as long as I'm a libpcap core developer, version 1.N+1 of libpcap will be API and ABI compatible with version 1.N, although it may have new capabilities - any program built with 1.N will work with 1.N+1, although programs built with 1.N+1, if they use any of those new capabilities, won't work with 1.N (that's the way software works).

Looking at the jnetpcap source from its SVN repository, the `releases/jnetpcap-1.3/release-1.3.0-1/src/deb/jnetpcap-1.control` file says:

```
Depends: libpcap-dev (>= 0.8)
```

and 0.8 is certainly >= 0.8, given that it's = (or, if you're writing C code, ==) 0.8.

Older jnetpcap releases had

```
Depends: libpcap0.8 (>= 0.9)
```

but even *that* shouldn't produce a dependency on "libpcap0.9", it should produce a dependency on libpcap0.8, with a version number >= 0.9.

And [wheezy has libpcap0.8 with a version number of 1.3.0-1](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libpcap0.8), and 1.3.0-1 is >= 0.9, so wheezy shouldn't have a problem with a package that depends on "libpcap0.8 (>= 0.9)" unless either 1) that Depends: line doesn't mean what I'd expect it to mean or 2) the dependency checking is broken and it doesn't realize that libpcap 1.3.0 is most definitely later than libpcap 0.9.